# ListView is automatically selecting random items

Tags: android, listview

I have a multi-select listview which have 4 textviews and 1 check box in each row. Now, when i select a checkbox and when i scroll down it selects another row randomly. For example if i select 1st item then when i scroll down the first item which comes on screen is selected and vice versa.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    Downloader d=new Downloader(MainActivity.this,urlAddress,lv);
    d.execute();

}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 Context c;
 ArrayList<PlayersPool> players;
 LayoutInflater inflater;
 boolean[] itemChecked;

 public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<PlayersPool> players) {
    this.c = c;
    this.players = players;

    //INITIALIE
    inflater= (LayoutInflater) 
 c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    itemChecked= new boolean[players.size()];
 }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return players.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return players.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return players.get(position).getId();
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
  parent) {
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);
    }

    final TextView nameP= (TextView) 
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameP);
    TextView priceP= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceP);
    TextView roleP= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.roleP);
    TextView team= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.team_name);
    final CheckBox chk= (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);

    nameP.setText(players.get(position).getName());
    priceP.setText(players.get(position).getPropellant()+" PKR");
    roleP.setText(players.get(position).getDescription());
    team.setText(players.get(position).getTeamName());




        chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String listItemText= nameP.getText().toString();

            if(chk.isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(c,"Checked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(c,"Not 
     Checked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      });
    }
```

I have tried a lot but i am not able to find out the error.

Comment: You have to track the checked state of your CheckBox and set it correctly in getView() (removing any OnCheckedChangeListener before that and setting it again afterwards)  because the CheckBox will keep its state when its parent ViewGroup (aka *convertView*) is passed into getView() for recycling

Answer (score 2):

`ListView` — like its modern replacement, `RecyclerView` — recycles rows. When the user scrolls the list, as rows scroll off the screen, they get reused by `getView()` for rows that need to scroll onto the screen.

You need to:

- Save information about what items are checked/unchecked somewhere, rather than showing `Toast` messages. For example, you could use your `itemChecked` array.
- In `getView()`, set the checked state of your `CheckBox` every time, based on whether the requested item has been checked (e.g., look up the value in `itemChecked`).

[This activity](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.13/Selection/RateList/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/ratelist/RateListDemo.java) demonstrates the basic technique, though in my case I am using a `RatingBar` instead of a `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your checkbox's state explicitly in getView(), based on whether it should be checked for that particular row or not.

The Views that are created to represent ListView elements are typically recycled when scrolling for performance reasons (which is what you're doing in your code with convertView), so any view properties that you don't re-set explicitly when you're reusing that View will simply retain whatever state they were in the last time that particular View instance was used.